# PIC12 TRIS Register not setting

Tags: c, assembly, pic

I'm trying to program a PIC12C508A to do a simple LED learning circuit.  I've read some examples, the Microchip Datasheet, pic12c508a.h and pic12c508a.inc.  I've tried to set the TRIS register using a C program and an ASM program but it does not take.  Using MPLAB X, the XC8 compiler, and the built in simulator to check the SFR registers I can see that the TRIS is not updating even when the WREG holds the correct values.  If anyone has experience with this please check out my code and see if I am doing something wrong.

```
#include <xc.h>

// -- CONFIG
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // RA5/MCLR/VPP Pin Function Select bit (RA5/MCLR/VPP pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Turn Watchdog Timer Off.
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
#pragma config OSC = IntRC      // Internal RC Oscillator

// -- Internal Frequency
#define _XTAL_FREQ 400000

int main()
{
    TRIS = 0b111010;  // 0x3A
           //---0-0 Set GP0 and GP2 as outputs

    GPIO = 0b000100;  // 0x04
           //---1-0 Set GP2 as HIGH and GP0 as LOW

    for(int countdown = 10; countdown > 0; --countdown) {
        __delay_ms(60000); // Delay 1 minute.
}

    GPIO = 0b000001;  // 0x01
           //---0-1 Set GP2 as LOW and GP0 as HIGH

    while(1)
        NOP();
}
```

I also tried it an assembly which is pretty much identical to the Gooligum tutorials for baseline PIC models.

```
  list  p=12c508a
  #include <p12c508a.inc>

  __CONFIG  _MCLRE_ON & _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF & _IntRC_OSC

RCCAL CODE    0x0FF   ; Processor Reset Vector
      res     1       ; Hold internal RC cal value, as a movlw k

RESET CODE    0x000   ; RESET VECTOR
      movwf   OSCCAL  ; Factory Calibration

start
      movlw   b'111010' ; Configure GP0/GP2 as outputs
      tris    GPIO      ;
      movlw   b'000100' ; Set GP2 HIGH - GREEN LED
      movwf   GPIO

      goto    $         ; loop forever

      END
```

This all seems pretty straight forward but when I use breakpoints and examine the SFR registers in the simulator I can see that the GPIO and TRIS registers never are changed even though the WREG will hold the correct values.  I've examined the ASM output that the XC8 compiler generates and it is almost identical to the ASM I wrote when it comes to setting the registers.

I've also tried using HEX values and straight integer values and the results are the same.

Comment: Is your internal XTAL frequency really clocked at 400KHz? Isn't it 4MHz? If it is so, change your **#define XTAL_FREQ 4000000**

Comment: @Jean-francois, That worked exactly! I cannot believed I overlooked that the whole time.  The PIC12 works correctly when programmed and installed on the breadboard.  The simulator still does not work correctly but the electronics.statckexchange.com board told me there is a bug in MPLAB X with the PIC12C range and the simulator not working.  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah because the PIC you are using is one very old one, not supporting quite well hardware debugging with a simulator. Upgrading to, let's say a PIC12F1840 would solve the problem while upgrading your software possibilities with many included peripherals. Good to know the problem is solved, I've posted the answer so this post may get the correct answer check. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that the crystal frequency defined at the top of the program was way beyond the real actual value

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 400000 //that's 400KHz INTOSC, impossible
```

Instead it should be

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000 //That's 4MHz INTOSC
```

@Justin pointed it out in the comment below it's original post.

Answer (score 2):

First, in order to use GP2 as an output, do you need to clear the T0CS in the OPTION register ?

Second, I observe this in the manual:

> Note: A read of the ports reads the pins, not the output data latches.
>   That is, if an output driver on a pin is enabled and driven high, but
>   the external system is holding it low, a read of the port will
>   indicate that the pin is low.

but I guess the simulator will assume the external system is not holding down the pin.

Third, `BCF` and `BSF` instructions look like a better way of waggling GP2 and GP0 independent of whatever else is going on in the GPIO.

I'm sorry, but other than that I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: I added `OPTION = 0b11011111` to the setup as you said.  The datasheet did mention clearing T0CS to use GP2 as output, I must have been fixated on something else but it was clear as day when reading over the OPTION register.  Still same situation.  I cannot get TRIS to take any value other than it's starting 0x3F value.

Comment: OK.  I note that the `TRIS` "register" is write-only, and I cannot see any way to read it.  So, what the simulator is showing you after `TRIS GPIO` (assuming that's `TRIS 6`) is a question for the simulator.

Comment: You read a port with PORT instruction.
`TRISB = 0b10101010;`
`ucReadPort = PORTB;`
`ucReadPortb should equal 0b10101010;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try different GPIO, because according to the documentation, GP2 may be controlled by the option register.

[image]